# Angular Mongo Db, select issue

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, node-webkit

I am writing desktop application with node webkit, angular and embedded mongodb.

I have a very strange issue with select. I have two schemas Orders and Customers.
Order points to customer with ObjectId.

I have created a simple crud with select on customer field in Order. It means to assign customer you need to choose him from a select list.

Once I open the existing order to update, the customers list bind select. But the value of select is showing empty. The list exists but the input empty.

Once I choose another customer and update everything works fine, but the select value just not showing on the screen. I can change the customer, it means that it updates the db with new value. The problem is only in the view.

Screenshot:

[image: Sorry can not show list opened]

Sorry can not show list opened, but all the values are there. And if click save the db is updated.

I just want to understand how it can happen? And how I solve it ...

I was building generic crud popup, that updates and create my models, and here is my code:

Order model:

```
model.factory('Order', function(db,Customer,Payment) {

    var schema = new db.Schema({
        customer : {type: db.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'customer'},
        name : { type: String, required: true },
        date : { type : Date },
        amount : {type:Number,default:0}
    });


    schema.statics.fields = [
        {
            type : 'date',
            name : 'date',
            label : 'Date'
        },
        {
            type : 'select',
            name : 'customer',
            label : 'Customer'
        },
        {
            type : 'text',
            name : 'name',
            label : 'Subject'
        },
        {
            type : 'number',
            name : 'amount',
            label : 'Amount'
        }
    ];

    return db.model('order', schema);
});
```

Popup directive:

```
directives.directive('popup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: './views/crud/button.html',
        scope:{
            model : '=',
            type : '=',
            title : '=',
            size : '=',
            id : '=',
            cb : '&'
        },
        compile: function(element, attrs){
            //Default Values
            if (!attrs.entity) { attrs.entity = 0; }
            if (!attrs.cb) { attrs.cb = function(){}; }
            if (!attrs.size) { attrs.size = 'sm' }
        },
        controller:function($scope,$modal){
            $scope.runPopup = function (){
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: './views/crud/popup.html',
                    controller: 'crudPopupCtrl',
                    size: $scope.size,
                    resolve: {
                        settings : function(){
                            return $scope;
                        }
                    }
                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                    console.log('model saved');
                    $scope.cb();
                }, function () {
                    console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                });
            }
        }
    };
})
```

Crud Popup Controller

```
controllers.controller('crudPopupCtrl', function ($scope,$state,$modalInstance, settings,$injector) {
        //settings is the scope that was passed from directive
        console.log(settings);
        $scope.title = settings.title;
        $scope.model = settings.model;
        if(settings.id){
            settings.model.findOne({_id:settings.id},function(err,entity){
                $scope.entity = entity;
                console.log('entity opened',$scope.entity);
            });
        }else{
            $scope.entity = new settings.model();
        }

        console.log('Opened',$scope.entity);

        //date
        $scope.open = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.opened = true;
        };
        $scope.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1
        };
        //----


        //need to bring dependent data for selects
        $scope.selects = {};
        switch($scope.model.modelName){
            case 'order':
                var Customer = $injector.get('Customer');
                Customer.find({},function(err,customers){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log('customers',customers);
                    $scope.selects['customer'] = customers;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });



                break;
        }

        $scope.submit = function () {
            if(settings.id){
                console.log('going to update',$scope.entity);
                $scope.entity.save(function(err){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    $modalInstance.close();
                });
            }else{
                settings.model.create($scope.entity,function(err,entity){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log('entity created',entity);
                    $modalInstance.close();
                });
            }
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    });
```

Popup view for previous controller, here is the bug:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h3>
</div>
<form name="entityForm" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in model.fields">
            <label>{{field.label}}</label>
            <div ng-switch="field.type">
                <select ng-switch-when="select" ng-model="entity[field.name]" class="form-control" >
                    <option value="{{select.id}}" ng-repeat="select in selects[field.name]">{{select.name}}</option>
                </select>

                <div ng-switch-when="date">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy" ng-model="entity[field.name]" is-open="opened"  datepicker-options="dateOptions"   close-text="Close" />
                                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                                  </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input ng-switch-default type="{{field.type}}" ng-model="entity[field.name]" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="entityForm.$invalid">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here I have select with options, this is 'the select'. I know that my implementation with options in not angular way, I was tried first with ng-options with the same effect.

This was my try:

```
ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in selects[field.name]"
```

Comment: The same is with insert.

Comment: This question needs a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code sample.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  It is impossible for us to tell you why your code isn't working from a screenshot of the incorrect behavior.